# Is it poor practice not to assign an instance of an object to a variable?

Tags: java, performance, swing, instantiation

Ok, so I have been java programming for a bit now, and occasionally I find that I need to create a new instance of an object, but I don't need the variable for reference, such as working with GUI's. When I work with a GUI, I will do something like this:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        /*
         * Setup main properties of window 
         */
        JComponent contentPane = (JComponent)getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());
        setTitle("Window Title");
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        //Add other stuff here

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

That way, whenever I need to instantiate the GUI, I just call:

```
new MainWindow();
```

However, I notice that Netbeans gives me a hint regarding this, so I know that it is not proper practice to do it that way.

That being said, what is the correct way to handle object instantiation when you don't need the variable?

Comment: It's worse practice if you assign it to a variable that you don't use.

Comment: I won't consider it a bad practice, but it may be considered by code review tools like PMD or Checkstyle.

Comment: Using a reference to an object is always helpful, if you need to use it again in your code.

Comment: I once wrote a whole game where everything was "self adding". You created a character and it added itself to the physics engine etc. Seemed really nice. Then one day I wanted to check if it was in collision first and only if it wasn't add it to the world. All the self adding stuff was an absolute nightmare and all had to be removed.  Not sure if your situation is exactly like this, but its worth considering. This seems like pretty much the top of the program though; is that the only place you would use this

Comment: +1 to @SotiriosDelimanolis - further, PMD and Checkstyle will complain if you assign it to a variable and then never use it again.

Comment: The concern I have is that you do all your set up in a constructor. In this simple example it's fine, but if you had your class implement some event handler, and if you added it as an action listener in your init method, then you would be exposing an instance of your class before its constructor had completed. This can come back to bite you.

Comment: Other than GUIs, the most common place I see this is to do async processes where you don't care about the result or where they use callbacks. Eg. `new AsyncEmailNotification();` But even in these cases, I prefer to see `asyncEmail.send()` or `process.start();` explicitly called to be clear what the intent is.

Comment: It might be considered bad practice to have a self executing constructor (some times, it's the only way to go), such as having the frame making itself visible from the constructor. It's also, generally, discouraged to extend from `JFrame` as you're not actually adding any new functionality to the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object is not referenced by any other object and could potentially be garbage-collected. If you only need a single instance in your application, you could use static method in the same class to implement a singleton, like this (the code below has not been compiled):

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static MainWindow instance;

    public static MainWindow getMainWindow() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MainWindow();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    private MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // ... skip original code for brevity ...
    }
}
```

Note that you could make the constructor private in this case.

**EDIT** corrected the instance to null comparison as per comments.

Comment: I think this solution is the most valid in my case as typically my GUI applications have one main window and then I just generate dialogs if I need anything else. In order for this to work in Java though, the if statement needs to be if (instance == null). The current form is standard C#

Comment: Yep, sorry. My C inner ego speaking. :)

Comment: The `Frame` can't be GC'd when it's visible (as it gets referenced by the AWT).

Comment: @maaartinus, you're right. i was not talking about this Swing code, but in general.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is bad practice; I agree with Sotirios Delimanolis that "It's worse practice if you assign it to a variable that you don't use."

But I do think that you can do a couple of things to make it clearer and easier to maintain.

- Wrap the call to `new ...` in a method that describes what it does. This makes it clear in code what your intent of calling the constructor is. It also makes it easy to change the way to do it later, if you need to.

Example:

```
private void instantiateTheGui() {
    new MainWindow();
}
```

- I think it might be a bad idea to do all that work in the constructor. Does every usage of that object want the same properties? Size? Visibility? Etc.? I would argue that the last line (`setVisible(true);`), at least, should be invoced by whatever code is calling the constructor because it may not want it to be visible immediately.

Now your code suddenly becomes:

```
private void instantiateAndShowTheGui() {
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now we have a variable, and a legitimate usage of it. I wasn't trying to get a variable, it happened with good design and responsibility separation.

My point is that there isn't anything inherently wrong about calling an object constructor without storing it in a variable, but I have never come across (IMO) nicely designed code that uses this pattern. It is not bad, but *clean* code often doesn't run into the problem.

Comment: Standard Java naming convention is for methods to begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thx, fixed! Too much C# lately... I almost wrote `var` too.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to create a class like this, because:

If onother developer reads this code (or your future-you) you may not remember why there is an unused object like that.

I would rewrite is a litle like and write something like

```
new MainWindow().show();
```

`show()` will call the `initComponent()`.